# how cout object's streambuf is initialized?

Tags: c++

I know cout is declared as
extern  ostream cout;

This is just an extern declation, so where is cout defined ?
How the streambuf of cout is initialized and how it is associated to standard output ?

ostream class has one constructor which takes streambuf pointer as the parameter.
So my understanding is somewhere cout has to be instanciated as
ostream cout(streambufPtr);  where do I find this ?

Thanks.

Comment: in a compilation unit somewhere in your compiler's std library implementation. That's why it's extern'ed

Comment: thanks Dave, I was expecting it in some other header file and was searching for it. Thankyou.

Comment: If you're interested in the specifications, have a look at §27.4.1.2 and §27.4.2.3 in N3845.

Answer (score 0):

The actual declaration of `cout` is required so that you can use it. The definition of it is not.

That's no different to something like the code making up the standard libraries - while you need the declarations, the definitions (the code implementing them) is not necessary to be visible to you.

Hence `cout` and its brethren are most likely stored in the C++ runtime/startup libraries somewhere, along with the code to attach it to standard output before your code is permitted to run.